# Image resizing before uploading by using HTML5 Canvas and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html5-canvas

**Reduce the size of images before submitting it to the web server by using HTML5 canvas.**

In my application is being used upload image. It takes very large images, minimum 10 MB per image, in total 60MB. This works nice in a WiFi connection but fails due to a slower mobile data connection. For this I have to upload the image before reduce the size (the image will upload after resize it), so that it can work properly mobile data connection.
But don't find any good reference to solved this problem. Someone please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When asking questions here you will want to provide a code sample that demonstrates what you have already tried.  Essentially stackoverflow isn't a code writing service.  Show us what attempts you have made to figure this out.

Comment: sorry about that.